# Dual monitor setup using startx not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have two Monitors which used to run two different application on each one. Eg.

- Monitor A should run chromium-browser
- Monitor B should run another chromium-browser

This should be run after system boots up.

#### xorg.conf below

```
Section "ServerFlags"

        # Even if mouse detection fails, X will start
    Option         "AllowMouseOpenFail" "yes"
        # VT switching is disabled
    Option         "DontVTSwitch" "yes"
        # X restart (Ctrl+Alt+Backspace) is disabled
    Option         "DontZap" "yes"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
   Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection


Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse1"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard1"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL ST2220M"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
     Identifier    "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 630"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1920x720"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier      "Screen1"
   Device      "Device0"
   Monitor     "Monitor1"
   DefaultDepth    24
   SubSection      "Display"
    Depth      24
        Modes      "1920x720"
   EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Screen 0 "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice "mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice "keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout1"
    Screen 1 "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice "mouse1"
    InputDevice "keyboard1" 
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection
```

In init script of runlevel 2, I have:

```
startx /path/to/screen-0-app.sh -- :0 -layout Layout0 -config /path/to/displaylink.conf -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -sharevts &

startx /path/to/screen-1-app.sh -- :1 -layout Layout1 -config /path/to/displaylink.conf -nolisten tcp vt8 -novtswitch -sharevts &
```

`displaylink.conf` as same as xorg.conf:

```
screen-0-app.sh and screen-1-app.sh consist of 

exec xterm -e xrandr -s 1920x1080 &

exec chromium-browser --user-data-dir=~/.chromium --window-size=1920,1080 --window-position=0,0 --kiosk --incognito http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRbI6LwLz94

another screen consist of different youtube link with same setup
```

The problem is, I am able get one monitor is working with this setup. Which means the following:

Youtube video playing in chromium-browser One startx is working but another monitor seems to blank and the error it's giving is:

```
(++) Using config file: "/home/atled/displaylink.conf"

(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

> xorg.0.log file
>    [    40.255]

```
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    40.255] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    40.255] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-26-generic i686 Ubuntu
[    40.255] Current Operating System: Linux atled-desktop 3.2.0-45-generic-pae #70-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:31:05 UTC 2013 i686
[    40.255] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-45-generic-pae root=UUID=8057523e-f126-4b9b-9534-b7c4cda86c8d ro acpi=off apm=off quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    40.255] Build Date: 04 August 2012  01:51:24AM
[    40.255] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    40.255] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[    40.255]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    40.255] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    40.255] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Jun  7 20:34:44 2013
[    40.256] (++) Using config file: "/home/atled/displaylink.conf"
[    40.256] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    40.265] (++) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    40.265] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    40.265] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    40.265] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    40.265] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    40.265] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    40.265] (**) Option "DontVTSwitch" "yes"
[    40.265] (**) Option "DontZap" "yes"
[    40.265] (**) Option "AllowMouseOpenFail" "yes"
[    40.265] (**) Option "Xinerama" "0"
[    40.265] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    40.265] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    40.265] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    40.265]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    40.265] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    40.265]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    40.265] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    40.265]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    40.265] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    40.265]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    40.265] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    40.265]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    40.265] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[    40.265]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    40.265] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        built-ins
[    40.265] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    40.265] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    40.265] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    40.265] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    40.265] (II) Loader magic: 0xb77195a0
[    40.265] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    40.265]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    40.265]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[    40.265]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[    40.265]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[    40.266] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0f00:19da:1282 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfb000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xce000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000ec00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    40.266] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    40.266] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    40.267] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    40.267] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.267]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    40.267]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    40.267]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    40.267] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    40.267] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    40.267] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.267]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    40.267]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    40.267]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    40.267] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    40.267] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    40.267] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    40.286] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    40.286]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    40.286]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    40.286] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:51:59 PDT 2013
[    40.286] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    40.286] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    40.286] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    40.286] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.286]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[    40.286] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    40.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    40.287] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.287]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    40.287]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    40.287] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    40.287] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    40.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    40.287] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.287]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    40.287]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    40.287] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    40.287] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    40.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    40.287] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    40.287]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    40.287]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    40.288] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:32:42 PDT 2013
[    40.288] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    40.288] (++) using VT number 7

[    40.288] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    40.288] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    40.288] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    40.288] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.288]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    40.288]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    40.288] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    40.288] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    40.288] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    40.288] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.288]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    40.288]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    40.288] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    40.288] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    40.288] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    40.288] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    40.288] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    40.288] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    40.288] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    40.288] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    40.288] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    40.288] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    40.288] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    40.878] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (DELL ST2220M (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[    40.878] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[    40.891] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Philips 224EL (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[    40.891] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[    40.894] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 630 (GF108) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    40.894] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[    40.894] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.08.aa.00.00
[    40.894] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    40.894] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    40.895] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): EVO Push buffer channel allocation failed
[    40.895] (EE)  *** Aborting ***
[    40.895] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to allocate EVO core DMA push buffer
[    40.895] (EE)  *** Aborting ***
[    40.895] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failing initialization of X screen 0
[    40.896] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    40.896] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    40.896] (II) UnloadModule: "wfb"
[    40.896] (II) Unloading wfb
[    40.897] (II) UnloadModule: "fb"
[    40.897] (II) Unloading fb
[    40.897] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    40.897]
Fatal server error:
[    40.897] no screens found
[    40.897]
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    40.897] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    40.897]
[    40.897]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
[    40.897] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Try setting it up using either `xrandr` or (better) `nvidia-settings` can you make it work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displays and monitors are not the same thing.

You're trying to start a separate X-server and display for each monitor, this is not what you want to do.

You want to start one X-server with 1 display (`:0`) and two monitors (`:0.0` and `:0.1`).

You should have one `startx` call to start up `:0`, and the script should launch both applications, moving one of them to the second screen with the `--window-position` parameter.

If your monitors are side-by-side, and the first one is 1920x1080 with a top-left corner of 0,0, then then second monitor's top-left corner will be 1920,0.

Comment: This idea is good,I can do that one but why  multiple xserver with different application not working.In my case i seen xorg.0.log and xorg.1.log are configuring monitor perfectly but only one display is up.

Comment: -windows-position is not working even i change the position.still application running in same monitor not on another one

Comment: X servers take exclusive control over a display device. According to your log, the X server on `:0` is taking control of both screens, which causes the X server on `:1` to be unable to bind to the second display. Note that if you run two X servers, you will not be able to drag a mouse between them, or drag windows from one screen to the other.

Comment: @aravindKrishna Did this finally work for you? I'm doing something similar and this is the closest I can find to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What Darth said. Also, in our `xorg.conf` you refer to both `monitor0` (for `screen0`) and `monitor1` (for `screen1`) but you only have one `monitor` section defined and that is `monitor0`.

My guess is that the no screens found error is because X is trying to find `monitor1` but that does not exist.

Comment: Its loaded my layout1, monitor1 and my monitor 1 is philips in xorg.1.log saying enable all display devices for philips.That means my configuration correct but way starting the x server as fault i think so